# JavaCard RSA Cipher DoFinal Exception

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, javacard

I have this Code to encrypt data with rsa:

```
private static RSAPrivateKey smartcard_rsa_private = (RSAPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PRIVATE, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512, false);
private static RSAPublicKey smartcard_rsa_public = (RSAPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_RSA_PUBLIC, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_512, false);
private static Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_RSA_NOPAD, false);

KeyPair kp = new KeyPair(smartcard_rsa_public,smartcard_rsa_private);
kp.genKeyPair();
smartcard_rsa_private=(RSAPrivateKey)kp.getPrivate();
smartcard_rsa_public=(RSAPublicKey)kp.getPublic();
byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
cipher.init(smartcard_rsa_public, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
cipher.doFinal(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short) apdu.setIncomingAndReceive(), buffer, (short)0);
```

I send the following APDU:

```
byte[] data = new byte [64];
new CommandAPDU(0x80, 0x01, 0x00, 0xff, data);
```

I get an Error Code 5 while the doFinal which should be the one of the following:

**CryptoException.ILLEGAL_USE if one of the following conditions is met:**

- This Cipher algorithm does not pad the message and the message is not
  block aligned.
- This Cipher algorithm does not pad the message and no
  input data has been provided in inBuff or via the update() method.
- The input message length is not supported or the message value is
  greater than or equal to the modulus.
- The decrypted data is not bounded by appropriate padding bytes.

Comment: Could you please tell us the APDU you send? It looks like padding issue.

Comment: @vojta I updated the Question

Answer (score 2):

Your plaintext is not block aligned, because your input data has length `64`, but the length of single RSA plaintext block with 512 bits of the public key is `53` bytes.

For a n-bit RSA key, direct encryption works for arbitrary binary messages up to `n/8 - 11` bytes (provided `n` is divisible by 8, which usually is, of course).

The real question is why to use RSA for encryption without any padding mechanism at all. There is no reason, really. Use `ALG_RSA_PKCS1` instead.

If you need to encrypt long data, encrypt it with AES and share the AES key encrypted with RSA together with the message. Asymmetric cryptography is awfully slow.

Comment: Being awfully slow is probably the least important reason why you would want to use RSA only for encrypting **random** keys for symmetric crypto instead of encypting actual data...

Comment: @MichaelRoland Improve my answer, please, if you have any ideas. I think speed is the most important reason... What other reasons do you know?

Comment: See e.g. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/126/25798 (TL;DR overhead in ciphertext size and getting block chaining right)